# Native C Extension if Library is Available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I'm building a native C extension Ruby gem for generating unique identifiers (found [here](https://github.com/ksylvest/identifier)). I'd like the library to use **libuuid** if possible (through C extensions) and fall back to a simple Ruby implementation. I currently have both the C and Ruby code for generating the UUID, however I can't figure out how to configure a successful fallback. Any ideas?

Comment: usually what developers do is provide a 'pure' and 'not-pure' version of the gem.

Comment: @Pablo As in two separate versions of the gem?

Comment: I think so, at least the `json` gem has a `json_pure` version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`have_library`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/files/mkmf_rb.html#M001212) method has a return value:

> Returns whether or not the given entry point `func` can be found within `lib`.

So you should be able to do this:

```
$defs.push('-DUSE_RUBY_UUID') if !have_library('uuid')
create_makefile("identifier")
```

And then set up your C to use **libuuid** if `USE_RUBY_UUID` is not defined and call into the Ruby UUID library if it is defined.

Oddly enough, the [`have_header`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/files/mkmf_rb.html#M001216) and [`have_func`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/files/mkmf_rb.html#M001214) methods in `mkmf.rb` add macros for you:

```
# File mkmf.rb, line 840
def have_header(header, preheaders = nil, &b)
  checking_for header do
    if try_header(cpp_include(preheaders)+cpp_include(header), &b)
      $defs.push(format("-DHAVE_%s", header.tr_cpp))
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

but `have_library` makes you do it yourself.

Comment: I would define all the methods in ruby first.  Then require the C extension.  If the library is found, override some ruby methods.  If not found, do nothing.

Comment: @David: That depends on how his existing C is set up. Bypassing Ruby completely and going straight to the C library would be a lot faster and probably a lot more convenient than taking a detour through Ruby's method resolution and marshalling/unmarshalling system.